# How to fix create-react-app not found in cmd error?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, create-react-app, npx

[I tried many ways but it is coming the same always Any way how to fix it?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOxTf.png)

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if you have npm install by typing npm --version
2. If you don't have npm follow this link to download Node.js to your computer. https://nodejs.org/en/download/
3. After installation you can use npx command.

Comment: npm is installed and its version is 6.14.12